# Django-import-export-celery Import error [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: django, ubuntu, file-permissions, django-import-export

I have a minor issue where I always see an error 13:

```
Import error [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/_/_/_/media/django-import-export-celery-import-change-summaries'
```

[image]

I can still import but I cannot see the end HTML template.

[image]

It's supposed to look like this (on my windows localhost):

[image]

I believe the blank summary is also caused by the Ubuntu file permission issue but I do not want to do anything because as I understand it, [granting permissions on a production server is dangerous](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303593/how-can-i-chmod-777-all-subfolders-of-var-www). Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just enabled permission with chown 755